# Related jobs in JSprit , One before another case : IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, routes, illegalargumentexception, jsprit

This question is related to this topic : [Related jobs in JSprit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447451/related-jobs-in-jsprit/36279434?noredirect=1#comment60185266_36279434)

I'm trying to use the "one before another" constraint but i'm experiencing a ***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: arg must not be null*** . It looks like Capacity cap2 is null when calculating Capacity max. I don't really understand why.

:(

Do you have an idea about this?

For the record, I'm on the **1.6.2 version**. TY for your help.

```
        String before = "2";
        String after = "11";

        final StateManager stateManager = new StateManager(problem);
        stateManager.addStateUpdater(new JobsInRouteMemorizer(stateManager));



        ConstraintManager constraintManager = new ConstraintManager(problem, stateManager);
        constraintManager.addConstraint(new OneJobBeforeAnother(stateManager, before, after));

        final RewardAndPenaltiesThroughSoftConstraints contrib = new RewardAndPenaltiesThroughSoftConstraints(problem, before, after);
        SolutionCostCalculator costCalculator = new SolutionCostCalculator() {

            @Override
            public double getCosts(VehicleRoutingProblemSolution solution) {
                double costs = 0.;
                List<VehicleRoute> routes = (List<VehicleRoute>) solution.getRoutes();
                for(VehicleRoute route : routes){
                    costs+=route.getVehicle().getType().getVehicleCostParams().fix;
                    costs+=stateManager.getRouteState(route, InternalStates.COSTS, Double.class);
                    costs+=contrib.getCosts(route);
                }
                return costs;
            }

        };
        VehicleRoutingAlgorithmBuilder vraBuilder = new VehicleRoutingAlgorithmBuilder(problem,
                "algorithmConfig.xml");
        vraBuilder.addCoreConstraints();
        vraBuilder.setStateAndConstraintManager(stateManager, constraintManager);
        vraBuilder.addDefaultCostCalculators();
        vraBuilder.setObjectiveFunction(costCalculator);
        algorithm = vraBuilder.build();



public class JobsInRouteMemorizer implements StateUpdater, ActivityVisitor {
private StateManager stateManager;
private VehicleRoute route;



public JobsInRouteMemorizer(StateManager stateManager) {
    super();
    this.stateManager = stateManager;
}

@Override
public void begin(VehicleRoute route) {
    this.route=route;
}

@Override
public void visit(TourActivity activity) {
    if(activity instanceof JobActivity){
        String jobId = ((JobActivity) activity).getJob().getId();
        StateId stateId = stateManager.createStateId(jobId);
        System.out.println(stateId.getIndex());
        System.out.println(stateId.toString());
        stateManager.putProblemState(stateId, VehicleRoute.class, this.route);
    }

}

@Override
public void finish() {}

}
```

Comment: Hi @Cédric Alexis, has your problem been resolved? I might have encountered the same issue. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot create StateId instances on the fly. All StateId instances have to be generated **before** the algorithm is run. See longer answer for why doing this is still not a good idea and you should consider a redesign.

Analysis: I ran into the same problem and traced it back to the way StateId instances are created in StateManager:

```
public StateId createStateId(String name) {
    if (createdStateIds.containsKey(name)) return createdStateIds.get(name);
    if (stateIndexCounter >= activityStates[0].length) {
        activityStates = new Object[vrp.getNuActivities() + 1][stateIndexCounter + 1];
        vehicleDependentActivityStates = new Object[nuActivities][nuVehicleTypeKeys][stateIndexCounter + 1];
        routeStatesArr = new Object[vrp.getNuActivities()+1][stateIndexCounter+1];
        vehicleDependentRouteStatesArr = new Object[nuActivities][nuVehicleTypeKeys][stateIndexCounter+1];
        problemStates = new Object[stateIndexCounter+1];
    }
    StateId id = StateFactory.createId(name, stateIndexCounter);
    incStateIndexCounter();
    createdStateIds.put(name, id);
    return id;
}
```

Each time you create a new StateId and there is no more space available for states the old state arrays are overwritten with a longer version to make space for your new state (at start there is space for 30 StateIds, a few already used by JSprit itself). As you can see, the old elements aren't copied over, so what happens here is a race condition between UpdateLoads, which sets the state used as cap2, your code, which generates a new StateId and overwrites the current state and UpdateMaxCapacityUtilisationAtActivitiesByLookingForwardInRoute which reads the state (that doesn't exist anymore).

Given that this code only extends the arrays by one it is **very inefficient** to have many StateIds, as for each new StateId all arrays have to be recreated. To mitigate this I used only one StateId in my code and stored a `Map<String, VehicleRoute>` in it:

```
Map<String, VehicleRoute> routeMapping = Optional.ofNullable(stateManager.getProblemState(stateId, Map.class)).orElse(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())
```

This way you don't run out of StateId instances and can still store relations between an unlimited number of jobs.